# raise self.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist( Portal.models.logger.Student.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: logger has no Student

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, web-development-server

I keep getting this error everytime I try to access the class assignment page.
Below is the code of my project.

Models.py

```
class logger(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Student(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(logger,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True,related_name='Student')
    name=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    roll_no = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['roll_no']

class Teacher(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(logger,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True,related_name='Teacher')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    class_students = models.ManyToManyField(Student,through="StudentsInClass")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('teacher_detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Views.py

```
@login_required
def class_assignment(request):
    student = request.user.Student
    assignment = SubmitAssignment.objects.filter(student=student)
    assignment_list = [x.submitted_assignment for x in assignment]
    return render(request,'class_assignment.html',{'student':student,'assignment_list':assignment_list})
```

class_assignment.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">

{% if student.student_assignment.count == 0 %}
  <h2>No assignments Yet</h2>
{% else %}
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Assignment Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Uploaded By</th>
        <th scope="col">Uploaded Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Download</th>
        <th scope="col">Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for assignment in student.student_assignment.all %}
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
          <td>{{ assignment.assignment_name }}</td>
          <td>{{ assignment.teacher }}</td>
          <td>{{ assignment.created_at }}</td>
          <td><a href="{{ assignment.assignment.url }}" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Download</a></td>
          {% if assignment in assignment_list %}
            <td>Submitted</td>
          {% else %}
            <td><a href="{% url 'submit_assignment' id=assignment.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</a></td>
          {% endif %}
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
{% endif %}
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Can anyone please help me and tell me if something is wrong in the code or not, I have tried almost everything including syncing the database, trying to migrate the project, deleting and re-creating the database.

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you and if you need anything else please comment and I'll upload it.

Comment: Likely the error is on the `student = request.user.Student` line, since for the `user` you are working with, there is no related `Student`.

Comment: That is highly unlikely  as the account which I used to access the webpage was a student account.

Comment: And in the models you can see in the student table, I have added the username with related name 'Student'

Comment: but it is not because the `is_student` field is `True` that there is a related `Student` model, in fact you do need to store `is_student` since that is implied by the existence of such record. Regardless, can you find a record in the database for the student with `username` having as value the primary key of the user you are working with?

Comment: exactly, but that does not mean each user has a `Student` object, it only means that each student is linked to a user, and that no two different students exist that point to the same user.

Comment: Hi, It would be really great if you could post the solution as I'm new to django and I dont have much knowledge, it would really be appreciated.